# Graph points on a coordinate plane

Tags: javascript, graph, coordinates

I need an interactive coordinate plane where the user can plot a coordinate himself. Something similar to :
https://www.ixl.com/math/grade-3/graph-points-on-a-coordinate-plane

Can any help with opensource library with the above functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the google scatter chart? At the end of the page they have a "Events" section, I think you can found what you need there.

Here you can read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart

Comment: I want the user to mark the co-ordinate on plane graph and then when the user submits I have to see whether he marked it correctly. Do you think its possible via google charts?